# How can create a nested array in php dynamically

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create a nested array in php. 
The structure of the array I am trying to create

```
array(
  'year' => 2017
  'month' => array(
       '0' => 'December',
       '1' => 'December',
   ) 

)
```

I am trying to create this array dynamically using array_push() function.

```
$date=array();
foreach ($allPosts as $p) {
    $year=date("Y", strtotime($p['published']));
    $month=date("F", strtotime($p['published']));
    array_push($date, $year);
    array_push($date['month'], array($month));
}
```

This don't work and it shouldn't :). But How can I achieve the structure dynamically.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't use `array_push()` to create associative arrays.

Comment: Got it. Then index will work? Let me try :) thanks

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. You have a loop in your code, but where would you put multiple years in the desired result?

Comment: I want to put the result in $date array which I am trying to make a nested array

Comment: I don't think you've really thought through the structure properly. What if you have posts from different years? You only have a single `year` key.

Comment: You probably want to use `year` as the key, and the value is an array of months.

Comment: Yes correct, just trying to create with one year.

Comment: Can you show what $p['published'] looks like? The contents of it or one of them?

Comment: Hi, it's working now from @Barmar's answer! Thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the array with the keys you want, and initialize the `month` element with an empty array.  Then fill them in in the loop.

```
$date = array('year' => null, 'month' => array());
foreach ($allPosts as $p) {
    $date['year'] = date("Y", strtotime($p['published']));
    $date['month'][] = date("F", strtotime($p['published']));
}
```

The final result will have the year of the last post, and an array of all the months.